# Common term for Resistance and Conductance?

Tags: resistance, impedance, conductance, admittance

Simple question; Impedance and Admittance are complementary quantities, and can be described by the common term "Immittance". Likewise Resistance and Conductance are complimentary quantities, do we have a word to describe both of these, like immitance but for resistance/conductance?

Comment: Immitance is still the correct term. If the imaginary part is 0, it describes resistance/conductance

Comment: @RJR Sure I know, I am asking if there exists a more explicit term for the "real part == 0" case.

Comment: Immittance is an "artificial" word invented for a specific application. It's existence does not imply existence of analogous terms.

Comment: @EugeneSh. "It's existence does not imply existence of analogous terms" Nothing implies that there would be an analogous term, but I see no reason there couldn't be one.. I am just asking whether anyone here knows of one.. BTW, what do you mean by "artificial" and what specific application are you suggesting that the word immittance was invented for???

Comment: @Vinzent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immittance